# Cadastro - comparaçao de valores existentes ou não

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro em PHP(funcionando normal), o meu problema é o seguinte na tabela tem um cadastro com o nome "Teste", e queria que quando fosse cadastrar outro user com o nome "Teste" ou "teste", não fosse possível cadastrar, porque já existe um valor igual na tabela.

Alguém tem uma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Use o método [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcasecmp.php) para comparar. Veja:

```
$var1 = "Teste";
$var2 = "teste";
if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0) {
    echo '$var1 é igual a $var2 numa comparação sem diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas';
}
```

Comment: Opa, esse metodo funcionou perfeitamente. obr

Answer (score 1):

Não sei que banco de dados você está usando, mas na hora da criação do banco de dados, no campo 'nome' você pode setar ele como **unique**, que *não será possível cadastrar outro com o mesmo nome.*

Você pode alterar a tabela já criada como o exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela
ADD UNIQUE (coluna);
```

Dessa forma, o próprio SGBD não permite insert de valor duplicado.

Comment: Particularmente não gosto muito desta abordagem, porque quanto menos requisição no banco, melhor. Apesar de ser algo pouco custoso, geralmente prefiro evitar, a não ser que seja um caso bem específico.

Comment: mas isso não é uma requisição, é uma proteção do BD em colocar nomes iguais para dentro, isso na verdade demanda da necessidade de mais proteção ou não. Em relação a performance certamente não perderá nada.

Comment: Estou dizendo requisição no sentido de consulta no banco. Qndo o cliente vai fazer qualquer tipo de consulta, primeiramente deve abrir uma conexão, etc. Isso sempre tem um custo, mesmo q seja um custo mínimo. Acredito que deve ser feito uma avaliação se de fato há necessidades de abrir uma conexão ou fazer o tratamento do lado do cliente. Mas cada um faz como acha que é melhor.

Comment: Aproveitando a questao. Estou tentando fazer um sistema de login, tipo na tabela ta com o valor "Teste" e no campo o user coloca "teste", como faço para validar o login com as diferenças de minusculas e maiusculas? Desculpem pela ignorancia estou sou novo na area...

Comment: @João Crie outro tópico para obter melhores respostas

Comment: @acklay Qual será o parametro de comparação se nao consultar o banco de dados então? Precisa verificar quais os valores já existentes na tabela e comparar com os valores fornecidos, sem parâmetro de comparação não é possível.